# How can i make offline apps using react-native

Tags: react-native

How can i make an offline app. For ex. user needs to use an app in offline like bible, dictionary app etc..

How can I make similar like this?

Answer (score 0):

Every mobile app is an offline app unless it communicate with a server via some sort of `https` request.

Anyway, I would suggest you look into `Async Storage` (built-in react-native) or i would personally use `SQLite`.

Make sure to save your data mostly or wherever possible as text and render it on some sort of object to display. which will take less space than images making your apps faster and smaller in size.